# S3 Staging option not available in Matillion Instance

Tags: matillion

I am going through Matillion Academy (Building a Data Warehouse). There is a slide deck to follow online and I am running my own instance of Matillion to recreate the building of the warehouse. I have entered all of the properties per the online instructions. It now tells me to select the S3 staging area. That is not an option on my instance and I cannot move forward.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image attached to your [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72190092/unable-to-connect-two-components-in-matillion), it looks like you are using Matillion ETL for Azure Synapse. That is an Azure-based solution, so the components will ask you to specify a Storage Account and Blob Container rather than an S3 staging area. Just choose one of your storage accounts and a container within it.

Similarly, if you were using Matillion ETL for Google BigQuery, the components would ask for a Cloud Storage staging area instead.

When you try to choose a Storage Account, if you find the dropdown list is empty, you will need to grant your Matillion ETL virtual machine access to one of your storage accounts first. Check the Access Control (IAM) tab in your Azure console, and use add role assignment if no storage accounts are shown.

While continuing the training course, if you come across any instructions to run an S3 Load, you will need to first use a [Data Transfer Component](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2953509) to get the files from S3 into your Azure blob container. Then use an Azure Blob Storage Load afterwards to load the data into your cloud data warehouse.