# Unable to connect two components in Matillion

Tags: matillion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QKRO.png)I have two components on a canvas in Matillion. The instructions are to "use my mouse to connect the two components". I am unable to connect them. I can drag them, but no connection is created.

Comment: can you put a screenshot of what the components are?  not all components connect with eachother.

Comment: I included a picture. I am attempting to connect the " start 0" to "create training_flights"

Answer (score 0):

This Matillion article on [Developing Workflows in Matillion ETL](https://www.matillion.com/resources/blog/developing-workflows-in-matillion-etl) might be helpful? There is a section on how to link Matillion ETL components.

In your Job, if you click on the "Start" to select it, you should then be able to drag out a link from its connector. Release the link on top of another (currently un-linked) component.

Answer (score 0):

Single click on the **Start** and hover over the circle (connector). Click from within this circle connector and move over to the other component. You should see the connecting line following behind your cursor.

Click on the second component and they should now be attached.